# Launch iPhone app after installation without user interaction

Tags: ios, iphone, device, launch

I want to create an iOS application where the application should launch automatically after it gets installed on the iphone device without any user interaction.

This application is for Enterprise (in-house application) only and it is not going to Appstore. Kindly let me know if this is possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: NO, its not possible without jailbreaking!

Comment: No its not possible. but if you want you can lock it to Single App mode via Guided Access(but still you need to launch the application).

Comment: Unfortunately no way.

Answer (score 2):

This can't be done. No third-party application can cause itself to run, it is one of the basics of iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Thank u all for the quick reply. I am able to relaunch the app when user kills the app manually or after the device restart now am looking for the solution to **launch application automatically for the first time after the installation**. I am not publishing the app on AppStore.

Comment: i also have this type of requirements. can you please share some logic?